# compact multiple-array implementation of doubly linked list with O(1) insertion and deletion

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am confused about my solution to an exercise (10.3-4) in CLRS (Cormen Intro to Algorithms 3ed). My implementation *seems* to be able to perform deletion + de-allocation in O(1) time, while two solutions I have found online both require O(n) time for these operations, and I want to know who is correct.

Here's the text of the exercise:

> It is often desirable to keep all elements of a doubly linked list compact in storage, using, for example, the first m index locations in the multiple-array representation. (This is the case in a paged, virtual-memory computing environment.) Explain how to implement the procedures ALLOCATE OBJECT and FREE OBJECT so that the representation is compact. Assume that there are no pointers to elements of the linked list outside the list itself. (Hint: Use the array implementation of a stack.)

By "multiple-array representation", they are referring to an implementation of a linked list using next, prev, and key *arrays*, with indices acting as pointers stored in the arrays rather than objects with members pointing to next and prev. That particular implementation was discussed in the text of Section 10.3 of CLRS, while this particular exercise seems to be simply imposing the addition condition of having the elements be "compact", or, as I understand it, packed into the beginning of the arrays, without any gaps or holes with "inactive" elements.

There was [a previous thread on the same exercise here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574182/how-to-implement-a-compact-linked-list-with-array), but that I couldn't figure out what I want to know from that thread.

The two solutions I found online are [first one here](https://ita.skanev.com/10/03/04.html) and [second one here, on page 6 of the pdf](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~ajl213/CLRS/Ch10.pdf). Both solutions say to shift all elements after a gap down by one in order to fill the gap, taking O(n) time. My own implementation instead simply takes the last "valid" element in the array and uses it to fill any gap that is created, which happens only when elements are deleted. This maintains the "compactness" property. Of course, the appropriate prev and next "pointers" are updated, and this is O(1) time. Additionally, the ordinary implementation from Sec. 10.3 in the book, which does not require compactness, had a variable named "free" which pointed to the beginning of a second linked list, which has all the "non-valid" elements, which are available to be written over. For my implementation, since any insertion must be done at the earliest available, e.g. non-valid array slot, I simply had my variable "free" act more like the variable "top" in a stack. This seemed so obvious that I'm not sure why both of those solutions called for an O(n) "shift down everything after the gap" method. So which one is it?

Here is my C implementation. As far as I know, everything works and takes O(1) time.

```
typedef struct {
    int *key, *prev, *next, head, free, size;
} List;

const int nil = -1;

List *new_list(size_t size){
    List *l = malloc(sizeof(List));
    l->key = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    l->prev = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    l->next = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    l->head = nil;
    l->free = 0;
    l->size = size;
    return l;
}

void destroy_list(List *l){
    free(l->key);
    free(l->prev);
    free(l->next);
    free(l);
}

int allocate_object(List *l){
    if(l->free == l->size){
        printf("list overflow\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i = l->free;
    l->free++;
    return i;
}

void insert(List *l, int k){
    int i = allocate_object(l);
    l->key[i] = k;
    l->next[i] = l->head;
    if(l->head != nil){
        l->prev[l->head] = i;
    }
    l->prev[i] = nil;
    l->head = i;
}

void free_object(List *l, int i){
    if(i != l->free-1){
        l->next[i] = l->next[l->free-1];
        l->prev[i] = l->prev[l->free-1];
        l->key[i] = l->key[l->free-1];
        if(l->head == l->free-1){
            l->head = i;
        }else{
            l->next[l->prev[l->free-1]] = i;
        }
        if(l->next[l->free-1] != nil){
            l->prev[l->next[l->free-1]] = i;
        }
    }
    l->free--;
}

void delete(List *l, int i){
    if(l->prev[i] != nil){
        l->next[l->prev[i]] = l->next[i];
    }else{
        l->head = l->next[i];
    }
    if(l->next[i] != nil){
        l->prev[l->next[i]] = l->prev[i];
    }
    free_object(l, i);
}
```

Comment: My answer here could be usable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39618642/905902 It does not use separate arrays for the struct members. Instead, it stores the DLL elements in contigious memory. Filling the hole (after a deletion) with (a copy of) the last element should be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct.

The O(n) "shift-everything-down" solution is also correct in the sense that it meets the specification of the problem, but clearly your approach is preferable from a runtime perspective.